# Extremely slow Wifi despite power management being turned off (Linux Mint)

Tags: networking, linux-mint, wifi

I am running *Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia (32 bit)*.  The WiFi on it is controlled by the `Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter`.  I noticed that the WiFi internet is really really slow on my linux mint.  I did a speedtest on linux mint and a windows machine and an android device within about 1 minute of each other.  My Linux Mint has a speed of about 3-5 Mbps while the Android and the Windows machine are much higher in the upper 30s.

I checked to see if WiFi power management was turned on using `iwconfig` and it is not.  See below output of `iwconfig`

> iwconfig  lo        no wireless extensions.
>
> enp3s0f0  no wireless extensions.
>
> wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"NetworkName"
>             Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: B8:8D:12:5D:C6:09
>             Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm
>             Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
>             Power Management:off
>             Link Quality=42/70  Signal level=-68 dBm
>             Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
>             Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:33   Missed beacon:0

**What is going on?  How do I fix this?**  [I already did change](http://www.upubuntu.com/2016/11/a-simple-tip-to-boost-your-wifi-signal.html) the /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf wifi.powersave value to 2 from 3.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Interestingly, I just checked the specs on another laptop I have: 64 bit linux Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.  Same Realtek chip (which must not be fed to dogs ;)) but the internet speed is much higher, even when the /etc/Network... power management is turned off.

Comment: Not surprising, but as you say power management bugs... I have here a couple of old, new, training and a work laptop...two Intel 5Ghz, an old Atheros, 2 Broadcoms and a realtek, and 2 ralink usb pens. realtek is a PITA,, Broadcoms can be temperamental on old versions the current one seem to work, atheros is (un)surprisingly exceptionally reliable and good for network tests, the  ralink can be a bit temperamental (bugs on old versions of Linux and *BSD), and the Intel, nothing out of ordinary, they just work.

Comment: With -68 dBm and 42/70 link quality, and assuming the windows machine runs on different hardware, my guess would be "bad antenna connection, antenna in unsuitable place". IIRC the 8188 driver also seems to have issues, so that could be also a reason. First thing is to move antenna around a bit and watch output of `iw station dump` (give it a few minutes to settle). Often a few centimeters can make a difference.